# Why was my programmers question closed but not one similar?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, programmers

My question was closed today: [What is programming like in the Japanese language?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46386/what-is-programming-like-in-the-japanese-language)

This question was never closed: [Do people in non-English-speaking countries code in English?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/do-people-in-non-english-speaking-countries-code-in-english)

Answer (score 6):

Well for one...your question is borderline a duplicate of that question, which by itself is justification for closure. However, the major difference is that your question is far to localized to be beneficial to the community. It is similar to asking "What can I expect as salary compensation in Japan?" The question that was not closed was far more general and was of value to a wide audience.

Comment: +1 This sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 4):

As Pemdas indicated, the other question is the *generalized* and more correct form of your question.

See:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

and

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask